# How to deal with collinearity or concurvity between fixed effect variables and random effect variables?

Tags: multicollinearity, glmm, generalized-additive-model, gamm4, concurvity

My current work involves asking subjects from different groups to pronounce multiple words, and I am interested in understanding the relationship between word duration and groups.

In R syntax, this can be expressed as:

`Duration ~ Group`

However, since there is a random effect on the durations that is unique to each subject, I plan to include the Subject variable as a random effect by using:

`Duration ~ Group + (1|Subject)`

The challenge is that the random effect variable `Subject` may be correlated with the fixed effect variable `Group`, leading to collinearity (in the case of LMM) or concurvity (in the case of GAM). Despite searching for answers to similar questions, I have yet to find a solution.